# How to converge 2 branches in Git

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Is there a way in Git to converge 2 branches with a single command?

Suppose I have a branch `feature1` where I'm developing a feature and another branch `feature2` where I'm developing another feature.

Now I would like to converge the 2 features since the development of `feature1` needs something developed on `feature2` branch and vice-versa.

AFAIK, I can achieve this by doing 2 merge, checking out `feature1`, merge `feature2` into it, then checking out `feature2` and merge `feature1` into it.

Is there a way to make the 2 branches converging into 1 point of merge with a single command? Next they continue again in their 2 separate branches.

Comment: You can just checkout feature1 and merge from feature2. Then forget (or even better delete) feature2

Comment: You could merge `feature2` into `feature1` and that would be your convergence point. Then you point your `feature2` branch to it and here you go

Comment: @black_fm: what do you mean with "you point your `feature2` branch to it"? Delete branch `feature2' after merge and create it again?

Comment: @ErniBrown: if I delete `feature2` and then I create it again (since development will continue on it even after merge) what happen to other people working on it after I pushed it?

Comment: @ABCplus a complete answer is a little complex, let just say that when you delete a branch from the remote (suppose `origin`) you are just deleting its ref, not all the commits the branch is made of. If someone push again `feature2` to origin then another `feature2` ref will be created (if allowed), with the same history of the old one. Be careful when deleting a branch someone else is working on

Comment: @ABCplus  you can point it with `git branch -f feature2 feature1` I think this should also not cause problems if you have collaborators (as in those on `feature2` should be able to simply `pull`) but I would test that first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this feature is not available with git out of the box. 
However you can create an alias:

`git config --global alias.sync="!git checkout $1 && git merge $2 && git checkout $2 && git merge $1"`

Then you would just do:

`git sync feature1 feature2`

And it would do the two merges for you

Comment: Keep in mind that by default doing 2 merges should work fine, but if you've configured git to not use fast-forwards then this will make a messy history.  Another option, after the first merge, is to directly relocate the other branch. There are several ways and I don't know a reason to prefer a specific one, but `git branch -f $2` would be one option